# Printing array of specific element

Tags: arrays, c, string, element

C programming:
Was assign to derive values from a text file using File i/o and print array of a specific element instead of everything in the array.

For example:
After accessing the file using File i/o, I use printf(“%s”, readings); and was able to print all the reading in the array. But i want to print a specific element in the array like: printf(“%s”, readings[4]); but nothing is printed when i input this line.

Comment: You need to use a format specifier which is matching the type of your element.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Without seeing some enough code it is difficult to guess what your problem might be. For example we don't know if the data type of `readings` is what we might guess from the two `printf` calls shown in your description. If the file I/O works as expected and you only have problems with the output you could fill your variables with hard-coded values instead. Show what input you use (if any), what output or error message you get and what you expect to get.